# Enable a disabled element through javascript .value = text

Tags: javascript, java, html, disabled-input

I want to bid on a collection through Javascripts .value function. When I enter a number in the price section through:

```
textObject.value = number
```

The "Make offer" Element of the website is still disabled so I cant proceed with the process. Is this something the website is preventing or why is the Make Offer button still disabled after entering a value with .value?

[image]

The website mentioned is opensea.io. If you are familiar with the web3 space you could reproduce my problem there if not I have found a similiar usecase on Twitter logins. When Logging into Twitter the first thing asked is the username. After entering the username you need to enter the password and the website element "Log in" is disabled as long as nothing is entered in the password element. However if we enter a password through textObject.value = text we get the same problem like before. The "Log in" element is still disabled.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

As I said you can reproduce the problem on Twitter logins or possibly every other website login structured with a disabled element, which needs a input in username / password to be enabled.

Comment: It is possible that they check if the event is created programmatically or not to block automated offers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. If this is the case do you know if there is some kind of workaround to achieve what Im trying to do @McGiogen?

Comment: their event listener to trigger a log in is probably never fired. Try using [dispatch event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) and making a [new Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) that bubbles. Probably an input event after content is changed.

Comment: could always use puppeteer and something like 2captcha for this as well.

Comment: Never heard of puppeteer before, but this seems to solve my problem thanks for the reply @asyncawait

Comment: no problem! good luck out there. Puppeteer is a package for node that allows you to control a browser through js. It gives you full control over a browser, including sending trusted events which can not be done through injected scripts in the console or extension functionality.